# RStudio Amazon EC2 & RGoogleAnalytics

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio, google-analytics-api

Could you help me, how to setup RGoogleAnalytics package at https://console.developers.google.com with Amazon EC2? On my mac works fine with localhost:1410, no problems.

- I installed httpuv on Amazon EC2 (missing package).
- Opened new window.

Here come the BUT: 
- something wrong.. message: "The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:1410 did not match a registered redirect URI."

I don't know why I got this message:

I created this **Authorized redirect URI**:
I try with: http://ec2-..-19-54-88.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:1410/ and with http://ec2-..-19-54-88.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/ too.
(.. = two numbers)

Any idea what is the problem? Why I got in the err message this link: localhost:1410.. (that is new OAuth credentials)

Many thanks,
Rrrr

Full Error message:

"Error: redirect_uri_mismatch 
Application: GAnalyitcs
You can email the developer of this application at: The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:1410 did not match a registered redirect URI."

Comment: As workaround you can use saved token.

Comment: Have you downloaded a new client_secret.json from the developer console after you changed the authorized redirect url from `http://localhost:1410` to `http://ec2...`? I have to assume the r library is picking up the redirect url from that file.

Comment: Yes, I see.. I don't know how could RStudio load this redirect URL. Because this is on a new server, clean R enviroment, clean code... I try to find the answer and post here.

Comment: Hello Matt, I solved that with a new developed httr auth, based on Hadley's advices. So, lot of prewritten code use :1410 port, but that isn't useful in a server..